# Change '1 Apr 2022, noon' to datetime format python

Tags: python

I want to change '1 Apr 2022, noon' to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format.

I know the `datetime` thing in python has the ability to parse but I am unsure how

Comment: Very few date/time parsers will recognize the string "noon".  What do you expect for other times of the day?

Comment: So it will say noon or midnight when it is 00:00 or 12:00, but all other times assign an HH:MM value

Comment: In my opinion (and it is just my opinion), it would be easier to do a string replace to change "noon" and "midnight" to "12:00" and "00:00".  After that, the standard `datetime` should be able to parse if with `strptime`.  Just an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`dateparser`](https://pypi.org/project/dateparser/) module's `parse()` function:

```
>>> from dateparser import parse
>>> parse("1 Apr 2022, noon")
datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 1, 12, 0)
```

This gets us a `datetime.datetime` object. We can now call [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) to format it properly:

```
>>> date_time = parse("1 Apr 2022, noon")
>>> print(date_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
'2022-04-01 12:00:00'
```

Comment: When I do this, I get this error: `Unknown string format: 1 Apr 2022, noon`

Comment: @user18580816 are you sure you're using the most recent version of `dateparser` and its dependencies? How did you install them?